# Difficult authorized_keys login problem only for root on Solaris 11

Tags: ssh, password, prompt

Here's a difficult ssh problem I can't figure out on Solaris 11, although I think I'm an experienced UNIX/Linux sysadmin. :)

I've copied the `root@server1:/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file to:

```
root@server2:/root/.ssh/authorized_keys

oracle@server2:/home/oracle/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

No problem logging on or running commands remotely for oracle@server2.

I keep getting the password prompt for root@server2.

If I run "sshd -d" (debug mode) on server2 and run "ssh root@server2 uptime" from server1, I get to see the following info on server2 until I get the password prompt and press Ctrl-C to interrupt it:

```
server2# /usr/lib/ssh/sshd -d
debug1: sshd version Sun_SSH_2.2
debug1: key_load_private: loading /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
debug1: ssh_kmf_check_uri: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Private host key #0 of type 1 (RSA).
debug1: key_load_private: loading /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
debug1: ssh_kmf_check_uri: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
debug1: Private host key #1 of type 2 (DSA).
debug1: Creating a global KMF session.
debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 22.
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
Connection from 10.71.4.10 port 21911
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version Sun_SSH_2.2
debug1: match: Sun_SSH_2.2 pat Sun_SSH_2.*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-Sun_SSH_2.2
monitor debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug1: Reloading X.509 host keys to avoid PKCS#11 fork issues.
monitor debug1: reading the context from the child
debug1: use_engine is 'yes'
debug1: pkcs11 engine initialized, now setting it as default for RSA, DSA, and symmetric ciphers
debug1: pkcs11 engine initialization complete
debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug1: My KEX proposal before adding the GSS KEX algorithm:
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: My KEX proposal I sent to the peer:
debug1: KEX proposal I received from the peer:
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha2-256 none
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha2-256 none
debug1: Host key algorithm 'ssh-rsa' chosen for the KEX.
debug1: Peer sent proposed langtags, ctos: en-US
debug1: Peer sent proposed langtags, stoc: en-US
debug1: We proposed langtags, ctos: de-DE,en-US,es-ES,fr-FR,it-IT,ja-JP,ko-KR,pt-BR,zh-CN,zh-TW,i-default
debug1: We proposed langtags, stoc: de-DE,en-US,es-ES,fr-FR,it-IT,ja-JP,ko-KR,pt-BR,zh-CN,zh-TW,i-default
debug1: Negotiated main locale: en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Negotiated messages locale: en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Host key type is 1.
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP sent
debug1: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 252/512
debug1: bits set: 2051/4095
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT
debug1: bits set: 2036/4095
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY sent
debug1: set_newkeys: setting new keys for 'out' mode
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: set_newkeys: setting new keys for 'in' mode
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: KEX done
debug1: userauth-request for user root service ssh-connection method none
debug1: attempt 0 initial attempt 0 failures 0 initial failures 0
Failed none for root from 10.71.4.10 port 21911 ssh2
debug1: userauth-request for user root service ssh-connection method publickey
debug1: attempt 1 initial attempt 0 failures 0 initial failures 0
debug1: ssh_kmf_key_from_blob: blob length is 277.
debug1: Test whether the public key is acceptable.
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 0/0 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: ssh_kmf_key_from_blob: blob length is 277.
debug1: matching key found: file /root/.ssh/authorized_keys, line 1
Found matching RSA key: 8e:7f:c6:54:09:e7:fa:6e:5c:cc:c7:13:e2:13:90:22
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug1: userauth-request for user root service ssh-connection method publickey
debug1: attempt 2 initial attempt 0 failures 0 initial failures 0
debug1: ssh_kmf_key_from_blob: blob length is 277.
debug1: We received a signature in the user auth packet.
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 0/0 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: ssh_kmf_key_from_blob: blob length is 277.
debug1: matching key found: file /root/.ssh/authorized_keys, line 1
Found matching RSA key: 8e:7f:c6:54:09:e7:fa:6e:5c:cc:c7:13:e2:13:90:22
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
Failed publickey for root from 10.71.4.10 port 21911 ssh2
debug1: userauth-request for user root service ssh-connection method keyboard-interactive
debug1: attempt 3 initial attempt 0 failures 2 initial failures 0
debug1: keyboard-interactive devs
Connection closed by 10.71.4.10
debug1: Calling cleanup 0x2df78(0xec5010)
debug1: Calling cleanup 0x262a8(0xece938)
debug1: Calling cleanup 0x53590(0x0)
monitor debug1: child closed the communication pipe before user auth was finished
monitor debug1: Calling cleanup 0x53590(0x0)
monitor debug1: Calling cleanup 0x53590(0x0)
```

More information on the SSH server configuration:

```
server2# diff /root/.ssh/authorized_keys /home/oracle/.ssh/authorized_keys
server2#

server2# ls -l /root/.ssh/authorized_keys /home/oracle/.ssh/authorized_keys
-rw-------   1 oracle   dba          396 Aug 29 08:53 /home/oracle/.ssh/authorized_keys
-rw-------   1 root     root         396 Aug 29 08:53 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

server2# ls -ld /root /home/oracle
drwxr-xr-x  30 oracle   dba           69 Aug 20 06:13 /home/oracle
drwx------  22 root     root          43 Aug 29 08:52 /root

server2# ls -ld /root/.ssh /home/oracle/.ssh
drwx--x--x   2 root     root           5 Mar 20  2014 /home/oracle/.ssh
drwx--x--x   2 root     root           3 Aug 29 08:53 /root/.ssh

server2# grep Root /etc/ssh/sshd_config
PermitRootLogin yes
```

Below shows the remote server server2's /var/log/authlog when I attempted `ssh root@server2 uptime` from server1:

```
Aug 30 09:46:48 db01 sshd[11916]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: Forked child 13172.
Aug 30 09:46:48 db01 sshd[13172]: [ID 800047 auth.info] Connection from 10.71.4.10 port 28154
Aug 30 09:46:48 db01 sshd[13172]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version Sun_SSH_2.2
Aug 30 09:46:48 db01 sshd[13172]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: match: Sun_SSH_2.2 pat Sun_SSH_2.*
Aug 30 09:46:48 db01 sshd[13172]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
Aug 30 09:46:48 db01 sshd[13172]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-Sun_SSH_2.2
Aug 30 09:46:48 db01 sshd[13172]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] monitor debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
Aug 30 09:46:48 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: Reloading X.509 host keys to avoid PKCS#11 fork issues.
Aug 30 09:46:48 db01 sshd[13172]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] monitor debug1: reading the context from the child
Aug 30 09:46:48 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: use_engine is 'yes'
Aug 30 09:46:48 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: pkcs11 engine initialized, now setting it as default for RSA, DSA, and symmetric ciphers
Aug 30 09:46:48 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: pkcs11 engine initialization complete
Aug 30 09:46:48 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
Aug 30 09:46:48 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: My KEX proposal before adding the GSS KEX algorithm:
Aug 30 09:46:48 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Aug 30 09:46:48 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
Aug 30 09:46:48 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: My KEX proposal I sent to the peer:
Aug 30 09:46:48 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: KEX proposal I received from the peer:
Aug 30 09:46:48 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha2-256 none
Aug 30 09:46:48 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha2-256 none
Aug 30 09:46:48 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: Host key algorithm 'ssh-rsa' chosen for the KEX.
Aug 30 09:46:48 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: Peer sent proposed langtags, ctos: en-US
Aug 30 09:46:48 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: Peer sent proposed langtags, stoc: en-US
Aug 30 09:46:48 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: We proposed langtags, ctos: de-DE,en-US,es-ES,fr-FR,it-IT,ja-JP,ko-KR,pt-BR,zh-CN,zh-TW,i-default
Aug 30 09:46:48 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: We proposed langtags, stoc: de-DE,en-US,es-ES,fr-FR,it-IT,ja-JP,ko-KR,pt-BR,zh-CN,zh-TW,i-default
Aug 30 09:46:48 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: Negotiated main locale: en_US.UTF-8
Aug 30 09:46:48 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: Negotiated messages locale: en_US.UTF-8
Aug 30 09:46:48 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: Host key type is 1.
Aug 30 09:46:48 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST received
Aug 30 09:46:48 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP sent
Aug 30 09:46:48 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 267/512
Aug 30 09:46:48 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: bits set: 2056/4095
Aug 30 09:46:48 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT
Aug 30 09:46:49 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: bits set: 2053/4095
Aug 30 09:46:49 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY sent
Aug 30 09:46:49 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: set_newkeys: setting new keys for 'out' mode
Aug 30 09:46:49 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
Aug 30 09:46:49 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
Aug 30 09:46:49 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: set_newkeys: setting new keys for 'in' mode
Aug 30 09:46:49 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
Aug 30 09:46:49 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: KEX done
Aug 30 09:46:49 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: userauth-request for user root service ssh-connection method none
Aug 30 09:46:49 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: attempt 0 initial attempt 0 failures 0 initial failures 0
Aug 30 09:46:49 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.info] Failed none for root from 10.71.4.10 port 28154 ssh2
Aug 30 09:46:49 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: userauth-request for user root service ssh-connection method publickey
Aug 30 09:46:49 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: attempt 1 initial attempt 0 failures 0 initial failures 0
Aug 30 09:46:49 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: ssh_kmf_key_from_blob: blob length is 277.
Aug 30 09:46:49 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: Test whether the public key is acceptable.
Aug 30 09:46:49 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 0/0 (e=0/0)
Aug 30 09:46:49 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: trying public key file /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
Aug 30 09:46:49 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: ssh_kmf_key_from_blob: blob length is 277.
Aug 30 09:46:49 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: matching key found: file /root/.ssh/authorized_keys, line 1
Aug 30 09:46:49 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.info] Found matching RSA key: 8e:7f:c6:54:09:e7:fa:6e:5c:cc:c7:13:e2:13:90:22
Aug 30 09:46:49 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Aug 30 09:46:49 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: userauth-request for user root service ssh-connection method publickey
Aug 30 09:46:49 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: attempt 2 initial attempt 0 failures 0 initial failures 0
Aug 30 09:46:49 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: ssh_kmf_key_from_blob: blob length is 277.
Aug 30 09:46:49 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: We received a signature in the user auth packet.
Aug 30 09:46:49 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 0/0 (e=0/0)
Aug 30 09:46:49 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: trying public key file /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
Aug 30 09:46:49 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: ssh_kmf_key_from_blob: blob length is 277.
Aug 30 09:46:49 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: matching key found: file /root/.ssh/authorized_keys, line 1
Aug 30 09:46:49 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.info] Found matching RSA key: 8e:7f:c6:54:09:e7:fa:6e:5c:cc:c7:13:e2:13:90:22
Aug 30 09:46:49 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Aug 30 09:46:49 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
Aug 30 09:46:49 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.notice] Failed publickey for root from 10.71.4.10 port 28154 ssh2
Aug 30 09:46:49 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: userauth-request for user root service ssh-connection method keyboard-interactive
Aug 30 09:46:49 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: attempt 3 initial attempt 0 failures 2 initial failures 0
Aug 30 09:46:49 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: keyboard-interactive devs
Aug 30 09:46:51 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.info] Connection closed by 10.71.4.10
Aug 30 09:46:51 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: Calling cleanup 0x2df78(0x34f960)
Aug 30 09:46:51 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: Calling cleanup 0x262a8(0x3592f8)
Aug 30 09:46:51 db01 sshd[13173]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] debug1: Calling cleanup 0x53590(0x0)
Aug 30 09:46:51 db01 sshd[13172]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] monitor debug1: child closed the communication pipe before user auth was finished
Aug 30 09:46:51 db01 sshd[13172]: [ID 800047 auth.debug] monitor debug1: Calling cleanup 0x53590(0x0)
Aug 30 09:46:51 db01 last message repeated 1 time
```

Also, below shows the output on server1 (on the originating server) when I used "ssh -v -v -v root@server2" from server1 to connect to server2:

```
server1# ssh -v -v -v root@server2
Sun_SSH_2.2, SSH protocols 1.5/2.0, OpenSSL 0x1000110f
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Rhosts Authentication disabled, originating port will not be trusted.
debug1: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to db01 [10.65.4.139] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: ssh_kmf_check_uri: /root/.ssh/identity
debug1: Identity file/URI '/root/.ssh/identity' pubkey type UNKNOWN
debug1: ssh_kmf_check_uri: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /root/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: no key found
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug3: key_read: no space
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: no key found
debug1: ssh_kmf_key_from_blob: blob length is 277.
debug1: Identity file/URI '/root/.ssh/id_rsa' pubkey type ssh-rsa
debug1: ssh_kmf_check_uri: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Identity file/URI '/root/.ssh/id_dsa' pubkey type UNKNOWN
debug1: Logging to host: db01
debug1: Local user: root Remote user: root
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version Sun_SSH_2.2
debug1: match: Sun_SSH_2.2 pat Sun_SSH_2.*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-Sun_SSH_2.2
debug1: use_engine is 'yes'
debug1: pkcs11 engine initialized, now setting it as default for RSA, DSA, and symmetric ciphers
debug1: pkcs11 engine initialization complete
debug1: Creating a global KMF session.
debug1: My KEX proposal before adding the GSS KEX algorithm:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,x509v3-sign-rsa,x509v3-sign-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: en-US
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: en-US
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug1: Failed to acquire GSS-API credentials for any mechanisms (No credentials were supplied, or the credentials were unavailable or inaccessible

)
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: kex_reset_dispatch -- should we dispatch_set(KEXINIT) here? 0 && !0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: My KEX proposal I sent to the peer:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,x509v3-sign-rsa,x509v3-sign-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: en-US
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: en-US
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug1: KEX proposal I received from the peer:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: gss-group1-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: de-DE,en-US,es-ES,fr-FR,it-IT,ja-JP,ko-KR,pt-BR,zh-CN,zh-TW,i-default
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: de-DE,en-US,es-ES,fr-FR,it-IT,ja-JP,ko-KR,pt-BR,zh-CN,zh-TW,i-default
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha2-256
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha2-256 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha2-256
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha2-256 none
debug1: Host key algorithm 'ssh-rsa' chosen for the KEX.
debug1: Peer sent proposed langtags, ctos: de-DE,en-US,es-ES,fr-FR,it-IT,ja-JP,ko-KR,pt-BR,zh-CN,zh-TW,i-default
debug1: Peer sent proposed langtags, stoc: de-DE,en-US,es-ES,fr-FR,it-IT,ja-JP,ko-KR,pt-BR,zh-CN,zh-TW,i-default
debug1: We proposed langtags, ctos: en-US
debug1: We proposed langtags, stoc: en-US
debug1: Negotiated lang: en-US
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: Remote: Negotiated main locale: en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Remote: Negotiated messages locale: en_US.UTF-8
debug1: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 262/512
debug1: bits set: 2025/4095
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: ssh_kmf_key_from_blob: blob length is 277.
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /root/.ssh/known_hosts
debug1: ssh_kmf_key_from_blob: blob length is 277.
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 17
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /root/.ssh/known_hosts
debug1: ssh_kmf_key_from_blob: blob length is 277.
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 17
debug1: Host 'db01' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:17
debug1: bits set: 2075/4095
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug3: kex_reset_dispatch -- should we dispatch_set(KEXINIT) here? 0 && !0
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: set_newkeys: setting new keys for 'out' mode
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: set_newkeys: setting new keys for 'in' mode
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: done: ssh_kex2.
debug1: send SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT
debug1: Authentications that can continue: gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex
debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Failed to acquire GSS-API credentials for any mechanisms (No credentials were supplied, or the credentials were unavailable or inaccessible

)
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/identity
debug1: ssh_kmf_check_uri: /root/.ssh/identity
debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277 lastkey 73cee8 hint 1
debug3: Pubkey type from SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_PK_OK is ssh-rsa.
debug1: ssh_kmf_key_from_blob: blob length is 277.
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp 8e:7f:c6:54:09:e7:fa:6e:5c:cc:c7:13:e2:13:90:22
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey
debug1: ssh_kmf_check_uri: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: ssh_kmf_check_uri: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
Password:
debug3: packet_send2: adding 32 (len 14 padlen 18 extra_pad 64)
Connection closed by 10.65.4.139
debug1: Calling cleanup 0x418a8(0x0)
```

Comment: did you check the directory permissions for /root and /root/.ssh yet ? anything looser than 700 perms, will cause you this problem.

Comment: SELinux permissions? Use more `-d` to get more debugging information.

Comment: (Original poster) Yep, I did. I included the directory permissions at the bottom of my posting.

Comment: (Original poster) To Jakuje - This happens between Solaris 11 servers.

Comment: What does your ~/.ssh/config file have in it on the originating server? (An empty or non-existent file is okay here.)

Comment: (Original poster) To John - No file existing for either /root/.ssh/ssh_config or /root/.ssh/config file and all commented out (default) for /etc/ssh/ssh_config file.

Comment: (Original poster) To Jakuje - Already tried using sshd -dd or -ddd on the remote server (server2) but the same info and no additional info is displayed.

Comment: I've edited your question slightly to make it more readable and comply with Stack Exchange guidelines. You've included lots of useful information in the question (so I'm upvoting it) but the most useful information would be the relevant entry in the SSH server log files.

Comment: (Original poster) To Anthony - That's a good idea! Just enabled the syslog level to auth.debug and I'm appending its output to my original posting now. Thanks.

Comment: (Original poster) Just appended "ssh -v -v -v root@server2" output to my posting above as well.

Comment: (Original poster) This probably happens on Solaris 11 servers only, as I have no problem on Linux servers, so I added "Solaris 11" to the subject and the beginning of the body.

Answer (score 0):

```
I've copied the root@server1:/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub file to:
root@server2:/root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

It depends how you copy.
So it is important to copy keys **not** via Cut & Paste between login-sessions.
Just use "scp" to copy your id_rsa.pub key from server1 to server2:

```
scp root@server1:/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@server2:/root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Make sure the permissions on the Home-Directory is not too open bit this will be reported by sshd to syslog.

regarding you output you may see (ssh -v -v -v root@server2):

```
key_read: no key found
```

It seems your id_rsa key is not valid. Please try to run a ssh-keygen to create a valid key and add the pub-key again.

Comment: (Original poster) To Malo - This is not the correct answer. Please read my original posting, as I already added the tightened permissions of related directories and files. No difference with the scp way of copying the file.

Answer (score 0):

as per log it is using ssh-rsa. you might have used `ssh-keygen -t rsa` to generate public key

```
debug1: Host key algorithm 'ssh-rsa' chosen for the KEX.
```

in the log it is trying with dsa algorithm.

```
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: ssh_kmf_check_uri: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
```

Please try generating public key with dsa algorithm

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa

ssh-copy-id -i /root/.ssh/id_dsa.pub server2
```